# Ensuring consistent network throughput from AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created few AWS EC2 instances, however, sometimes, my data throughput (both for upload and download) are becoming highly limited on certain servers.

For example, typically I have about 15-17 MB/s throughput from instance located in US West (Oregon) server. However, sometimes, especially when I transfer a large amount of data in a single day, my throughput drops to 1-2 MB/s. When it happens on one server, the other servers have a typical network throughput (as previously expect).

How can I avoid it? And what can cause this?
If it is due to amount of my data upload/download, how can I avoid it?

At the moment, I am using t2.micro type instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, don't use micro instances.

AWS is a multi-tenant environment as such resource are shared. When it comes to network performance, the larger instance sizes get higher priority. Only the largest instances get any sort of dedicated performance.

Micro and nano instances get the lowest priority out of all instances types.

This matrix will show you what priority each instance size gets:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-type-matrix

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of it. It seemed to work for N. Virginia server. But on most others (e.g. Tokyo, N. California), I am actually getting better throughput with the free instances.

Comment: You will see quite a bit of difference from one instance to the next. Ultimately depends how noisy your neighbors are.